# How can I generate an RSA public/private key-pair and use them to encrypt/decrypt NSData on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cryptography, commoncrypto

This is for an open source project which I am starting, so ideally I would like to use other open source works that I can include.

For the curious: I'm looking to encrypt an AES key using RSA.  I will then use AES key to encrypt/decrypt the user's data.

Comment: BTW, I'll come back here and link to the open source project once it's underway.

Comment: Just be careful with the licenses to the pieces. For a discussion (somewhat slanted) see http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it will be MIT for sure.